# Get 2 unique sub-lists both containing variable from a 2D list

Tags: prolog

So I have a 2d list and need to get 2 unique sublists from it both containing some variable X. For example if I have `[1,2],[2,3],[4,5],[3,4]` then the valid returns are `[1,2],[2,3]`, `[2,3],[3,4]` and `[4,5],[3,4]` of which any are valid.

I have defined a function resolve/3 that is as follows

```
resolve(List, X, New) :-
    member(A, List),
    member(B, List),
    member(X, A),
    member(X, B).
```

and an output is as follows

```
1 ?- resolve([[a,a],[a,b],[c,b]], b, M).
false.

2 ?- resolve([[a,a],[a,b],[c,b]], a, M).
true .
```

I've used `trace.` and for the failing call the cause is it doesnt backtrack. The trace can be found [here (pastebin link).](https://pastebin.com/VKcPvrxf)

Comment: You didn't use New in the body of resolve

Answer (score 0):

Based on @gusbro's comment, the following code works:

```
resolve(List, X, [A,B]) :-
    member(A, List),
    member(B, List),
    member(X, A),
    member(X, B),
    \+ A = B.
```

Please note the last element of the body to ensure that the lists are distinct (in the sense that they cannot be unified). However, answers will be duplicated as the order is ignored in the `member` predicate.

So, an alternative solution could look like the following piece of code:

```
solve_helper([X|Xs], [X, List]) :-
    member(Element, X),
    member(List, Xs),
    \+ List = X,
    member(Element, List).

solve_helper([_|Xs], Result) :-
    solve_helper(Xs, Result).
```